# Can regex alternatives (a|b|c) work together with the end of the pattern?

Tags: regex

I have a regex pattern that I'm using to try and match anything wrapped in an `<a>`, `<em>`, or quote `"`.

```
(?:<a.*?>|<em>|")(.*?)(?:"|<\/em>|<\/a>)
```

However, what I'd like to do is force the `<a>`'s to work together, and the `<em>`'s and so on. What I want *not* to happen is it to match a string that starts with an `<a>` but ends with a `"`.

For example:

```
<a href='google.com'>"Google"</a>
```

Should return `Google` and (probably also `"Google"`, but thats not a big deal). However, at the moment, its returning `href='google.com'>` as a match (and completely ignoring "Google") since it starts and ends with the "correct" patterns.

You can see all the ways this particular pattern breaks [here on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/PiYaMK/2).

**So is there a way to tell regex that if it starts a match with `<a>` that it must finish with `</a>` (and the same for the other patterns)?**

Comment: Bad example, to parse HMTL, use a HTML parser

Comment: I'm not trying to parse HTML though, I have a bunch of noise that I'm trying to get specific values out of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a *back reference*:

```
<(a|em|")[^>]*>(.*?)(?:</\1>)
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/SX2jYP5sXH).

Your target is in group 2 (there's no avoiding capturing the tag as group 1 if you use a back reference).